# How to wait until only the first thread is finished in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

The requirement is to start five threads, and wait only in the fastest thread. All five threads went to look for the same data 5 directions, and one is enough to continue the control flow.

Actually, I need to wait for the first two threads to return, to verify against each other. But I guess if I know how to wait for the fastest. I can figure out how to wait for the second-fastest.

A lot talk about `join(timeout)`, but you don't know in advance which one to wait (which one to apply `join` in advance).

Answer (score 29):

Use a queue: each thread when completed puts the result on the queue and then you just need to read the appropriate number of results and ignore the remainder:

```
#!python3.3
import queue    # For Python 2.x use 'import Queue as queue'
import threading, time, random

def func(id, result_queue):
    print("Thread", id)
    time.sleep(random.random() * 5)
    result_queue.put((id, 'done'))

def main():
    q = queue.Queue()
    threads = [ threading.Thread(target=func, args=(i, q)) for i in range(5) ]
    for th in threads:
        th.daemon = True
        th.start()

    result1 = q.get()
    result2 = q.get()

    print("Second result: {}".format(result2))

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Documentation for `Queue.get()` (with no arguments it is equivalent to `Queue.get(True, None)`:

> Queue.get([block[, timeout]])
>
> Remove and return an item from the
>   queue. If optional args block is true and timeout is None (the
>   default), block if necessary until an item is available. If timeout is
>   a positive number, it blocks at most timeout seconds and raises the
>   Empty exception if no item was available within that time. Otherwise
>   (block is false), return an item if one is immediately available, else
>   raise the Empty exception (timeout is ignored in that case).

Comment: Won't this raise an `Empty` exception if the Queue is empty when you do `q.get()`?

Comment: @Michael, the default for `q.get()` is to do a blocking get, so no it won't throw an exception instead it will block the main thread until there is a result available.

Comment: @Duncan Shouldn't one after the two q.get()'s terminate the active threads in order to finish cleanly?

Comment: @PeterMueller for this example it isn't needed: they aren't daemon threads so the script will wait for them to terminate before it exits. For real code though you might well want to wait.

Comment: There is no way this works. We only want to wait till the fist one is done

Comment: @CharlieOConor if you only want to wait for the first result then call `q.get()` once and use that result.

Answer (score 7):

If you have some sort of processing loop in your threads, the following code will terminate them when one terminates by using a [threading.Event()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects):

```
def my_thread(stop_event):
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        # do stuff in a loop

        # some check if stuff is complete
        if stuff_complete:
            stop_event.set()
            break

def run_threads():
    # create a thread event
    a_stop_event = threading.Event()

    # spawn the threads
    for x in range(5):
        t = threading.Thread(target=my_thread, args=[a_stop_event])
        t.start()

    while not a_stop_event.is_set():
        # wait for an event
        time.sleep(0.1)

    print "At least one thread is done"
```

If your process is "cheap" or a single request-response type thread (i.e. for instance an async HTTP request) then [Duncan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17565516/233608) is a good approach.

Comment: Can't `threading.Thread.is_alive()` function be used as a replacement to the `threading.Event()`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an event for this. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects
The idea is that the worker threads raise an event when they are finished. The main thread waits for this event before continueing. The worker thread can set a (mutexed) variable to identify itself with the event.

Answer (score 2):

Duncan's method is probably the best and is what I would recommend.  I've been mildly annoyed by the lack of "wait for next completed thread to complete" before, though, so I just wrote this up to try it out.  Seems to work.  Simply use `MWThread` in place of `threading.thread` and you get this new `wait_for_thread` function.

The global variables are a bit klunky; an alternative would be to make them class-level variables.  But if this is hidden in a module (mwthread.py or whatever) it should be fine either way.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

# Example of how to "wait for" / join whichever threads is/are done,
# in (more or less) the order they're done.

import threading
from collections import deque

_monitored_threads = []
_exited_threads = deque()
_lock = threading.Lock()
_cond = threading.Condition(_lock)

class MWThread(threading.Thread):
    """
    multi-wait-able thread, or monitored-wait-able thread
    """
    def run(self):
        tid = threading.current_thread()
        try:
            with _lock:
                _monitored_threads.append(tid)
            super(MWThread, self).run()
        finally:
            with _lock:
                _monitored_threads.remove(tid)
                _exited_threads.append(tid)
                _cond.notifyAll()

def wait_for_thread(timeout=None):
    """
    Wait for some thread(s) to have finished, with optional
    timeout.  Return the first finished thread instance (which
    is removed from the finished-threads queue).

    If there are no unfinished threads this returns None
    without waiting.
    """
    with _cond:
        if not _exited_threads and _monitored_threads:
            _cond.wait(timeout)
        if _exited_threads:
            result = _exited_threads.popleft()
        else:
            result = None
    return result

def main():
    print 'testing this stuff'
    def func(i):
        import time, random
        sleeptime = (random.random() * 2) + 1
        print 'thread', i, 'starting - sleep for', sleeptime
        time.sleep(sleeptime)
        print 'thread', i, 'finished'

    threads = [MWThread(target=func, args=(i,)) for i in range(3)]
    for th in threads:
        th.start()
    i = 0
    while i < 3:
        print 'main: wait up to .5 sec'
        th = wait_for_thread(.5)
        if th:
            print 'main: got', th
            th.join()
            i += 1
        else:
            print 'main: timeout'
    print 'I think I collected them all'
    print 'result of wait_for_thread():'
    print wait_for_thread()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just keep track of all finished threads in a list and let the second thread to finish handle whatever is supposed to be done, Python lists are threadsafe.

```
finished_threads = []
event = threading.Event()

def func():
   do_important_stuff()

   thisthread = threading.current_thread()
   finished_threads.append(thisthread)
   if len(finished_threads) > 1 and finished_threads[1] == thisthread:
       #yay we are number two!
       event.set()

for i in range(5):
    threading.Thread(target=func).start()

event.wait()
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the bit about the main thread waiting until two threads are complete and then continuing: instead you've transferred all the remaining activity onto the second thread to complete which may not be what is wanted.

Comment: true; handle_two_threads_done() should probably set on an Event instead. Edited.

Comment: Ummm, Python lists are threadsafe?  Really?  I thought one needed to use a Queue() for thread coherency!

Comment: The lists are safe, their data is not (like other Python builtins). In this case, they are safe because there is no race condition. If you need to synchronize on a list, you need a Queue. I try to avoid having to synchronize though.

Answer (score -2):

I think if you want to wait you should use the time library.
console:

> pip install time

code:

```
import time
time.Sleep(5)#seconds
```