# Stop script, EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, process, multiprocessing

I run a script that executes multiple processes, that are executed in different classes. The processes do not end unless the user asks for it. So in the main class I decided to create a process that will exit() the script, I supposed this will kill all the processes too. This is the main.py class.

```
def finishTest():
    end = "notexit"
    while end != "exit":
        end = input("To finish the test type 'exit'")
    exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    fT = Process (target=finishTest)
    fT.start()
    #this are functions of this class that call functions from other classes that run the other processes.
    askTest()
    execTest()
```

When I execute the main.py the following error appears,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "execution.py", line 20, in finishTest
    exit = input("To finish the test type 'exit'")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

How do I correct this error? Isn't it this a correct way to stop a script and all the processes being executed by the script?

Thank you all!

Comment: First of all you should think about renaming your exit variable (as `exit` is a pre-existing function), second, I don't think the issue is in the function you shared here (`finishTest()`) - just tried running it alone and aside from an error on the exit function it works fine

Comment: @DirtyBit if the user types "exit" in the prompt, then `exit` will be set to "exit"

Comment: @JessicaChambers Nope, it would throw an error:     `exit()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: Because the variable name is the same as the function name, hence my comment about renaming the variable.
In either case I don't recieve the `EOF` error

Comment: with some tweaks I have this which runs error free:
```
my_exit = "notexit"
while my_exit != "exit":
    my_exit = input("To finish the test type 'exit'")
print("bye bye!")
```

Comment: I rename the variable to "end". Doesn't work executing it in shell neither in Pycharm.

Comment: @Nkolot do you still have the `EOF` error?

Comment: yes I do,   File "execution.py", line 20, in finishTest
    end = input("To finish the test type 'exit'")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: is the error thrown before or after you have typed something? Before or after you type "exit"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the variable `exit` name and try putting it in a try-except block:

```
def finishTest():
    ex = "notexit"
    while ex != "exit":
        try:
            ex = input("To finish the test type 'exit'")
        except EOFError:
            pass
    exit()
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
To finish the test type 'exit'hey
To finish the test type 'exit'okay
To finish the test type 'exit'bye
To finish the test type 'exit'exit

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: This corrects the EOFError but logically executes an infinite loop. I get out the print message out of the while loop, it seems that works fine but the script doesn't stop.

Comment: @Nkolot It does not, added a sample output.

Comment: I get out the print message out of the while loop, it seems that works fine but the script doesn't stop.

Comment: Which script does not stop? What do you get?

Comment: The main.py script, the one and only I'm executing...I have processes inside but just one script.

Comment: @Nkolot That is expected behaviour, think of it as `n` number of threads executing and calling the function `finishTest()`.

Comment: @Nkolot read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564804/how-to-wait-until-only-the-first-thread-is-finished-in-python

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will look it and stake out the way to finish the processes.